# Why do these two Python imports work differently?

Tags: python, import, module, package

Assume the following code structure:

```
#### 1/hhh/__init__.py: empty

#### 1/hhh/foo/__init__.py:
from hhh.foo.baz import *

#### 1/hhh/foo/bar.py:
xyzzy = 4

#### 1/hhh/foo/baz.py:
import hhh.foo.bar as bar
qux = bar.xyzzy + 10
```

I run `python` inside `1/` and do `import hhh.foo.baz`. It fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "hhh/foo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from hhh.foo.baz import *
  File "hhh/foo/baz.py", line 1, in <module>
    import hhh.foo.bar as bar
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Now I replace `baz.py` with:

```
# 1/hhh/foo/baz.py:
from hhh.foo.bar import xyzzy
qux = xyzzy + 10
```

and again do `import hhh.foo.baz`. Now it works, although I’m loading the same module, only binding a different name.

Does this mean that the distinction between `import module` and `from module import name` goes beyond just identifiers? What exactly is going on here?

(I know I can use relative imports to work around all this, but still I’d like to understand the mechanics. Plus I don’t like relative imports, and neither does PEP 8.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write `from hhh.foo.bar import xyzzy` Python interpreter will try to load `xyzzy` from module `hhh.foo.bar`. But if you write `import hhh.foo.bar as bar` it will try first to find `bar` in `hhh.foo` module. So it evaluates `hhh.foo`, doing `from hhh.foo.baz import *`
. `hhh.foo.baz` tries to evaluate `hhh.foo`, `hhh.foo`tries to evaluate `hhh.foo.baz`, cyclic imports, exception.

Answer (score 0):

in `1/hhh/foo/__init__.py` you need to set the `__all__` list with the names of what you want to export. i.e. `__all__ = ["xyzzy"]`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you import from hhh.foo.bar in hhh.foo? `import bar` should suffice there.